# Renamed file in local git repository and remote has now both the old and new file

Tags: git, github, version-control, rename

I've just locally renamed my `README` to `README.md` in my git repository with:

```
mv README README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "renamed README"
git push origin master
```

I think I read that git would understand the `mv` command and therefore not keep the obsolete `README` file. However on GitHub, I now have both `README` and `README.md`.

I've tried to:

```
git rm README
git add -A
git commit -m "removed obsolete README"
git status
```

Which just results in

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

How do I correctly remove the obsolete `README` file locally, without interacting with the GitHub website.
And for the future, how do I correctly rename files/directories in a git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For renaming a file, do

`git mv README README.md` 
`git commit -m "file renamed"` 
`git push origin master`

Comment: So my mistake was, that I added the file again, after renaming it, right?
How do I fix my error?

Comment: So after you committed "removed obsolete README", you can push your changes so the the old file removal will reflect in git hub too